# TextBox with Custom Style not firing GotFocus

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, styles, controltemplate

I have what to some may seem like a simple problem and despite my best efforts, I have been unable to 'fix' this problem:

I have a custom style for a TextBox, defined in a 'common' assembly; this style overrides the default and is thus used every time someone uses a TextBox.
The problem is that when the style is applied, the GotFocus, IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged and PreviewGotKeyboardFocus events are -not- fired any longer.
I've verified that this only happens when this style is applied (If I comment it out and run the application, the events are fired correctly).

So my question is essentially, has anyone experienced anything similar? And if so, does anyone know of a solution for this problem?

The style is as follows (The static resources a simple SolidColorBrushes):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BrushBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxContextMenu}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{StaticResource BrushHighlight}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                  Margin="0" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushLightBg}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushMouseoverBackground}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi thi is working just fine here, I had to add some colors you were missing, which will make your eyes bleed pardon that, but I'm in a bit of a rush here :)

```
<!-- nice colors you were missing them ;) -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushBorder" Color="Blue"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxContextMenu" Color="DeepPink"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushForeground" Color="Red"/>        
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushHighlight" Color="Aqua"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushBackground" Color="DarkBlue"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushLightBg" Color="LightSeaGreen"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushMouseoverBackground" Color="Yellow"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TextBoxStyleMessed" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" >
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BrushBorder}"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxContextMenu}" />-->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{StaticResource BrushHighlight}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="0" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushLightBg}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushMouseoverBackground}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

.....

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="Hello!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyleMessed}" 
             x:Name="HateThisNonMVVMStuff"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1">Hodwy</Button>
</Grid>
```

Had to cut some corners but nasty codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HateThisNonMVVMStuff.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus += HateThisNonMVVMStuff_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus;
        HateThisNonMVVMStuff.LostFocus += UIElement_OnLostFocus;
        HateThisNonMVVMStuff.GotFocus += UIElement_OnGotFocus;

    }

    void HateThisNonMVVMStuff_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("PrevLostFocus!");
    }

    private void UIElement_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Hei! Gained focus");
    }

    private void UIElement_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Hei! Lost focus");        
    }
}
```

The events fires with your style, I applied it like a style for this one box only. I got an exception on your contextmenu and that it wouldn't have my nasty color, but hey, who would! :D

Hope it helps,

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: So you -are- getting the Focus events I mentioned? Where exactly are you adding handlers for those? I'm adding them through a separate behaviour class, and they're working just fine without the style - but not WITH the style.

Comment: @MelanieSchmidt added them in nasty codebehind there, had to cut som corners. but they fire at will here. Forgot to paste it in.

Comment: Okay this is really strange - they're now working for me as well... Must've been a fluke... Marking your answer as solution, thanks for your time!

Comment: Promise me you make a viewmodel and use eventocommand for removing the nasty codebehind! ;) I got some exception with the contextmenu, that's why I remmed it out. But I don't have time to check if this was the problem. It might actually been just vs for all I know.

Comment: The style is used from within a view, which is bound to a viewmodel - the only thing the events are used for is to 'select all' (And this is done from a separate Behaviour class) - Such that the xaml code for a TextBox in my app would look something like: `<TextBox TextSelectionBehaviour.AutoSelectOnFocus="True" Text="{Binding Whatever}"/>` - Don't worry, there's NO code behind apart from the auto-generated stuff :P

Comment: @MelanieSchmidt Hehe I was messing with you a bit there, as I didn't have time for creating a vm :) But good girl! Behaviours are also an awesome feature of WPF, but that one there looks like an AttachedProperty! No biggie! ;) +1 though